# how to change the encryption key in config/app.php to a key that will be retrieved from a different server or different database in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Can there be database connections made in the config/app.php ? Or is there any way, I could change it to a key that I will retrieve from a different server or different database (basically the key is outside the application).

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just wonder why do you need to do that ?

Comment: security reasons. I need to use a key that is provided by a external source. I want to dynamically set it in the config/app.php